# store percent value in mysql using bigdecimal

Tags: java, mysql, bigdecimal

How do I store percent value in MySQL using BigDecimal?

I used the following code to do so:

```
chngePer=new BigDecimal(st.nextToken().trim().replace("%", "")).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
```

but it gives me numberFormatException.

I am using a CSV file and storing each of its values in stringTokenizer st. One of its values is like -0.45%. How do I store it in the database?

```
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(nextLine, ",");
chngePer=new BigDecimal(st.nextToken().trim().replace("%", "")).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
```

**edit : contents of token**

- "TATA CONSULTANCY "
- 654914
- 5
- +2.2999
- "+0.19%"
- "5/23/2012"

Comment: `new BigDecimal("-0.45%".replace("%", "")).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))` works for me.

Comment: @juergen d- i have decimal(6,3) as the datatype of the column. is that causing the problem?

Comment: Please show the content of your tokens.

Comment: @juergen d- edited my question to include the tokens

Comment: Where do you get the exception? If it is while inserting in DB then please show that code.

Comment: @juergen d- edited my question, pls refer to my edited question and tell me how do i fetch back the data with + or - sign

Comment: Only remove the quotes. If you remove the `-` you will never know if a number was positive or negative.

Comment: i removed only the quotes not the - sign, still i get the unsigned value...i have edited my question again to include the code to removce the quotes...pls refer...

Comment: The code for parsing the percentage number is ok. It worked for me and the `chngePer` variable is signed. If your result is not ok after reading it from the DB then show that part of the code.

Comment: i havent coded that part yet. i just thought logically that if say for eg -0.45% is getting stored as 0.045 then how can it be retrieved as a signed percent value?

Comment: if you only remove the quotes and not the minus then all is fine.

Comment: i coded for it and all is not fine...pls refer to my re-edited question and see the code to fetch the data from db...i am getting an unsigned value.

Comment: Firstly; is your resulting BigDecimal signed or unsigned. If it's still unsigned, then we haven't fully resolved this. If it is signed, but turns unsigned after a trip to the database, then you have a problem with your db layer. If you do, and you need assistance with it, it feels to me that you should post a new question.

Comment: @Buhb- the resulting bigDecimal is unsigned for eg. -0.45% gets converted to 0.045 and is sstored in the database as it is. what should i do?

Comment: I removed the second question you edited in for you. You should post a new one about the sign so that it gets proper attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to remove the quotes.

Comment: thanks mate i removed the quotes and the value is now stored in the databse(withdout the + or - sign). but now at the time of retrieving the data back from the databse, how do i get back the + or - sign?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to remove the "+" sign. I've edited my answer.